# Heisenberg's uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

How can I apply Heisenberg's uncertainty principle in a standard R-L-C circuit to find the probability of an electron at a point in the circuit

Answer (score 1):

The Uncertainty Principle tells you nothing about the position itself, or the momentum itself.  Its about the size of the error in knowing both quantities at the same time.

In any case, in an RLC circuit there are an enormous number of electrons.  If, for example, the wire is made of copper each atom in the wire has 29 electrons, and there's something like $10^{22}$ atoms in even a gram of copper, then you can see that locating one electron is pretty pointless, especially on the human scale.  That number is a rough estimate using [Avogardo's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) as a starting point.

Many of these electrons are not even tightly bound to the individual atoms, but are mobile between the atoms (in fact this is what makes metal what it is).  If you're interested this explains more : [Metallic Bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_bonding).

Comment: I was thinking something else. Using the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle we can get a plot of the probability of finding and particle in space, right? So if I take a p-n junction diode in forward bias then can this concept be applied to find probability of an electron exiting the diode ?